# subprocess "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

What am I doing wrong? I have a command that I can run in the commandline that finds the total duration of all video files in a directory which works.

```
find /Volumes/Storage/test -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc
```

It works fine it outputs the number of second > 456.766000 which is what I want.

Now when I wrote the python script to do it says `No such file or directory` and doesn't output the number line the commandline command ended up doing.

Code

```
import subprocess

result2 = subprocess.run(['find', '/Volumes/Storage/test -maxdepth 1 -iname \'*.mp4\' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc'])
print (result2)
print ("-------")
```

Error:

```
No such file or directory

find: /Volumes/Storage/test -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc: No such file or directory
CompletedProcess(args=['find', "/Volumes/Storage/test -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \\; | paste -sd+ -| bc"], returncode=1)
```

Shlex output

```
['find', '/Volumes/Storage/test', '-maxdepth', '1', '-iname', '*.mp4', '-exec', 'ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=p=0', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '{}', ';', '|', 'paste', '-sd+', '-|', 'bc']
```

Comment: You must make each part of the command line a single string. Right now you have one huge string containing all arguments to find.

Comment: So you can't use a single command string?  You have to concatenate the string to smaller pieces into a variable? The add that variable to the subprocess?

Comment: See the "Note" that relates to using `shlex.split()` in https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EYJaaDUL  did that but didn't work

Comment: `subprocess.run` runs exactly one program. You are trying to run a pipeline, where `find` feeds into `paste` and `bc`.  You have two choices: construct a long pipeline and feed it to `os.system`, or construct your own pipeline by doing a chain of three `subprocess` calls.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the direction. I'm coming close.. https://pastebin.com/1qEWhye5  now do you know why the the output doesn't set to the variable?

Comment: I misled you.  To CAPTURE the output, you'd have to use a subprocess chain.  You could. however, use redirection:  add ` > /tmp/xxx` and read the contents of the file after.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
# Python program to explain os.system() method 
    
# importing os module 
import os 

# Command to execute 
cmd = 'find /Volumes/Storage/test -maxdepth 1 -iname \'*.mp4\' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc'

# Using os.system() method 
out = os.popen(cmd).read()

print("Output:",out)
```